# Create table in hbase

Tags: hadoop, key, hbase, row

I am new to hbase and hadoop. Anyhow I have succeeded in setting up a hadoop cluster which consists of 3 machines. Now I need some help on building up the database.

I have a table "comments" contains fields:

1. user id
2. comments
3. comments on comments (which can be more than one) and a status field to the same say,

Could any one help me out to build the same using hbase/shell?

Answer (score 8):

Here's some helpful HBase shell commands for you.  Get help on format for creating a table in the shell.

```
help 'create'
create 'comments', {NAME=>'user_info'}, {NAME=>'comment_data'}
```

Note that column families need to be explicit, but actual columns themselves have no requirements and can be added post-create just by doing a Put.  1 File per Column Family, all columns for a row in the family are adjacent to each other in the file.  In this case, I made a 'user_info' family that you could put 'user_id' and 'status' columns into.  Ditto for 'comment_data'.

If you need to alter the table (for example, you might only create one column family on the first try), you need to disable the table then alter it

```
disable 'tableName'
help 'alter'
enable 'tableName' # when done altering
```

Note that you also need to disable a table to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

The below link is a good resource for the HBase shell, including how to create a table.
<strike>http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell</strike>

**Update**
New URL is http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#shell

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to HBase, then you probably best to try a GUI for HBase administration - [HAdmin](https://hadmin.io/?utm_source=so&utm_campaign=createTable). Click to the "Tables" link on the sidebar, you will see all already existed tables and "Create table" button. 
[image: HAdmin full view]
Click to it and in the "Create table" page you can add your new table with all settings and column families you need.
[image: HAdmin create table]