# How to create a table in H base-shell without passing values & rowid?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hbase

hello "I m new to Hbase.. My question is How to create a table in hbase with column family & column names inside the columnfamily  without passing values and row key?Is it possible to create that table in hbase shell?

In Sql we create a table first and later we add data ..same thing how can we do it in hbase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create table in hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077577/create-table-in-hbase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HBase is a nosql key value database. The tables can be created just by specifying table name and column family for example `create "sampletable","m"` where sampletable is table name and m is column family. If you want to use SQL queries on HBase try Apache Phoenix.